# Why did Gandhari curse Sri Krishna?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, curse, gandhari

I have heard that Gandhari cursed Sri Krishna .But I dont know why ,can anyone please explain. And I also want to know that whatever Sri Krishna was 100% correct then Why did she curse.